# Setting Ros package path

Tags: robotics, ros

I just began exploring ROS from the ros.org. I'm having some trouble setting the environment in Ubuntu. I get the following error while trying to set up a workspace automatically every time a new shell is launched.

bash: /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash: No such file or directory

bash: /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your ROS installation added this to your ~/.bashrc file and somehow the setup.bash file got (re)moved.
Try to locate that file and change the path accordingly. This should set the required enviroment variables in order to run ROS (core) etc.
Check answers.ros.org for ROS-related Q&A. The wiki is also a good source of information: www.ros.org/wiki.

Answer (score 0):

First, open terminal and type the following command:

```
gedit .bashrc
```

Then press Ctrl + F and search fuerte. Delete everything about fuerte. Fuerte is old, download the new version groovy..

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of ROS have you installed. There are newer versions of ROS like ROS groovy.
Probably you installed a new one, but follow the guide for the old ROS fuerte. First make sure which distro have you installed.